# Mostrar imagen segun tamaño de pantalla

Tags: html, html5, responsive

Quiero que me muestre la imagen movil01.jpg cuando se ve desde el celular/movil y que me muestre la otra imagen en los otros tamaños de pantalla.

La verdad es que no se que estoy haciendo mal, independientemente del tamaño de pantalla siempre me muestra slide01.jpg, también he probado con src en lugar de srcset, y todas las combinaciones posibles pero nada, y mis navegadores están actualizados.

```
<picture>
<source srcset="images/movil01.jpg" media="(max-width:400px)">
<img src="images/slide01.jpg">
</picture>
```

Comment: Hola Andres, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Qué navegador usas? Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Has probado con css?

Comment: He probado el código que compartes y a mí me funciona sin problemas. ¿Te aparece algún error en la consola? A veces los `srcset` lanzan errores raros y los puedes ver allí (p.e. una vez haciendo pruebas con `srcset`, las imágenes tenían una url https pero se pedían por http rompiéndolo todo).

Answer (score 7):

Me parece que el problema es que en el atributo `media` lo declaras mal.

El `max-width`,   debería ser algo como esto:

```
media="(max-width: 400px)"
```

Con ello mostrará esa imagen cuando el maximo de la pantalla sea inferior a 400px.

Otro modo es que acotes dentro de `min-width` y hagas el proceso a la inversa. Poniendo la imagen `slide01.jpg` con un `min-widht:400px` de ese modo solo aparecerá cuando la pantalla supere los 400px y la otra imagen se mostrará cuando sea inferior.

Comment: hola! fue un error al escribir la pregunta, porque en mi codigo lo tengo como tu has puesto, ya lo he corregido en la pregunta, tambien he probado acotandola dentro de 'min-width' pero en este caso solo me muestra movil01.jpg, los navegadores en los que lo he probado son chrome y firefox ambos actualizados. podria ser algo con mi css?

Comment: @AndresArias, si no nos muestras tu `CSS` es bastante difícil saber si es por esa razón. Edita tu pregunta y agrega solo lo que este afectandolo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar esto en tu `CSS`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    body {
        background-image: url("images/slide01.jpg");
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 399px) {
    body {
         background-image: url("images/movil01.jpg");
    }
}
```

Lo he puesto con el body, pero si trabajas con clases o ids, lo puedes aplicar donde quieras

Answer (score 1):

Aunque puedo darte la respuesta para que lo soluciones "manualmente" debo decantarme por recomendarte usar algún **framework** que te facilite el **diseño responsive** (que es lo que tu deseas el poder visualizar una imágen según determinada resolución de pantalla o una imagen distinta si la resolución es menor).

**Bootstrap** es un excelente **framework** que te permite realizar tu diseño con la mejor calidad sin dedicarle tanto tiempo (manualmente te tocaría diseñar cada uno de los estilos para cada una de las imágenes y demás elementos que tengas en tus formularios). Más información sobre Bootstrap en [Página oficial de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

**Solución utilizando Bootstrap:**

Para instalarlo basta con que descargues el el **.zip** disponible en la referencia anterior que te dí, creas una carpeta llamada **"accesorios"** en la raíz de tu proyecto, descomprimes el **bootstrap.zip** en la carpeta **"accesorios"**.

Luego ya sería incluir los archivos en tu formulario, de la siguiente forma:

```
<link type="text/css"  href="accesorios/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="carpetajquery/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="accesorios/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**Observación**: Es sumamente importante cargar el jquery antes de bootstrap de otra forma no funcionará (para versiones anteriores a Bootstrap 4 ya que la 4 no la he probado aún).

Luego sencillamente usas los estilos de bootstrap para lograr lo que quieres. Así:

```
<picture>
<img class="hidden-xs img-responsive"  src="images/slide01.jpg">
<img class="visible-xs" src="images/movil01.jpg">
</picture>
```

Si quieres ajustarlas a otras resoluciones para que aparezcan o desaparezcan puedes leer [Características de cada rejilla](http://librosweb.es/libro/bootstrap_3/capitulo_2/tipos_de_rejillas.html) bootstrap.

Te dejo el código que hice para mostrarte lo que quieres pero con los **CDN de bootstrap**, es decir, están los fuentes online lo recomendable es que los descargues y los tengas en la **raíz de tu proyecto** como te mencioné al principio.

Para probar que una imagen aparece mientras la otra desaparece al cambiar la resolución sólo debes hacer **zoom en tu navegador**. Para hacer zoom debes presionar las teclas <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> para aumentar y para minimizar es <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<picture>

<img class="hidden-xs img-responsive"  src="https://entretengo-mundonetcolombia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/la-prueba-canal-caracol.jpg">
<img class="visible-xs" src="http://puntoverdeleon.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/imagen-de-prueba-320x240.jpg">
</picture>
```

Comment: Con `scrset` las imágenes sólo se cargan si se cumple la condición especificada y si no se cumple ninguna se carga el `img` por defecto. Pero sólo se carga una imagen. Con esta solución, se necesitan 3 ficheros (jQuery y Bootstrap, aunque puede que el usuario ya los esté usando) y además se cargan todas las imágenes del `picture`, lo que impactará el rendimiento/tiempo de carga de la página.

Comment: Concuerdo contigo en lo del rendimiento, sin embargo, intenté mantener la solución lo más sencilla posible en vista de que debí extenderme explicando sobre el bootstrap. Lo de los 3 ficheros es irrelevante ya que forma parte del funcionamiento de bootstrap y si representara alguna desventaja o desmejora por ello el framework no sería tan demandado o ya hubiese caido en desuso

Comment: Si el usuario ya las está usando no hay impacto ninguno; pero si no, es una desventaja/empeoramiento considerable que se añadan solo para usar 3 clases (se podría copiar el CSS de esas clases y ahorrarse 300KB). Me refería a eso.